# Photoshop: edit specific frequency band independently

Tags: adobe-photoshop

this question is targeted at people who understand something about fourier transform and the image pyramid.

Is there some plugin for photoshop that allows me to edit only a particular frequency band of a layer?

for example, sometimes you have an image that looks quite alright in the details but you have some low-frequency gradient going over the whole image that you'd like to get rid of.

it'd be great to decouple low and high frequencies of the image, edit only the low frequencies and then recomposite them again.

hope you know what I mean and maybe you know a way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: This would be better on Stack Overflow or Super User. It has to do with image analysis, not design. FFTs aren't a designer's stock in trade.

Comment: yeah but I know the theory behind it and also use it in programming - however - I want such a tool in Photoshop

Comment: I understand completely! I can think of about a dozen uses for such a plug-in, now that you've brought it up. It's just that this isn't the right place to ask the question. See the FAQ for guidelines. (BTW: If you decide to write one yourself, let me know.)

Comment: I would say that asking about a particular plugin could be considered on-topic in some regards.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question interesting so i come to know about Image [Pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_%28image_processing%29) &  [Fourier_transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) its completely scary mathematical term used for  calculating image.

`Fourier transform and the image pyramid. Even its completely complicated for a normal graphic designer guy to understand , we only design graphics , image composition is damn so technical,Mathematical, it completely deals with`   [typical image processing](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aY40C9o7-XeUJ%3amesh.brown.edu/engn1610/szeliski/03-ImageProcessing.pdf%20fourier%20transform%20and%20the%20image%20pyramid%20in%20photoshop&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjgBauwDFd9X2vkQ9zrnOg6Rt01lSnzwul9Ki_Ku8Rwi_RqQIwy0qXyucBFgK5spbtjV7KTIa69xJFpFoH84TLLARGv-yx8-ch0iHWzfd2u_2rul7S2KaIbzpU1rFQSi7WveMhW&sig=AHIEtbR989NtR0HsoXiAjIEb2JM39PqWxg) `which is not at all related to Graphic Design`

May be my answer is not related to your question but mean while you can check these links lighting on how to edit **image frequency** with the help of Photoshop, might be you get some clue to solve your issue

1. [Low and High Frequency Editing in Photoshop](http://www.redbubble.com/people/alisonjohnston/journal/5275304-low-and-high-frequency-editing-in-photoshop)
2. [Something about Low Frequency Deconvolution & Supplemental Sharpening](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~binaryfx/smartersharpen.html)
3. [Frequency Domain Techniques ( Mat-lab ) Introduction to Advanced Image Processing.](http://www.sigmacumlaude.com/sigmacumlaude/yetanotherforum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=33)
4. [Editing an image using high and low frequency](http://scanmyoldphotos.com/wordpress/?p=410)

---

May be  these plugin can help you

- [Fourier Transform plug-in](http://photoshop.pluginsworld.com/plugins/adobe/1028/4n6site-com/fourier-transform-plug-in.html)
- [Free Fourier Transform Plug-In to remove moire patterns](http://www.lunacore.com/blog/?p=87)

---

PS : I am really very sorry if my answer is completely out of track for you.

Comment: Good bit of digging, there, Jack!